# Is $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x-1}}{n!}$ a known thing?

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, exponentiation, eulers-number-e

I don't know much about math though I want to learn everything about it.
I was just in the wikipedia page of the Euler's number which says

$e=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$

I also know something about the Exponential function $f(x)=e^x$

So what I just done is multiplying $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ by itself to get $e^2$

and I got something like this:
$e+\frac{e}{2}+\frac{e}{6}+\frac{e}{24}+\frac{e}{120}...$

and then i figured out that $e^x$ equals $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x-1}}{n!}$

Is this a known thing? Sorry for wasting your time if it is, I just want to know more about these things.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x-1}}{n!} = e^{x-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} =  e^{x-1}  \cdot e = e^x$, that does not look very interesting as a fact on its own :)

Comment: Yes it's true, but what you end up with is a trivial equality related to the one you start with (as pointed out above). It's like starting with $x = x$ and ending up with $x = 2\cdot \frac{x}{2}$. Not anything new, but at least you ended up with something that's true which is always a good thing!

Comment: You'll never learn everything about math. What I think you should do is start learning some things about some parts of math. Find the things that interest you and pursue them more deeply.

Comment: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ is what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

If this all started because you were squaring the series $\sum_n\tfrac{1}{n!}$, you probably want to see how we show the exponential series satisfies $\exp(x+y)=\exp x\exp y$. It follows by the binomial theorem:$$\begin{align}\exp(x)\exp(y)&=\sum_{k,\,l\ge0}\frac{x^ky^l}{k!l!}\\&=\sum_{k,\,l\ge0}\frac{\binom{k+l}{k}x^ky^l}{(k+l)!}\\&\stackrel{\star}{=}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}\\&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}\\&=\exp(x+y).\end{align}$$In particular, $\star$ defines $n:=k+l$ and rearranges a double sum by the [Fubini principle](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ecmart07/fubini.pdf), exploiting the fact that $\tfrac{1}{n!}$ decays superexponentially, and therefore there are no convergence issues. (The above principle's [equivalent on integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) is what we would normally intend by "Fubini's theorem".)